# GET more objects using httr package in R

Tags: r, get, httr

I use `httr` package to GET data from Data API:

```
request3 <- GET(url = "https://api.data-api.io/xxxxx/", add_headers('x-dataapi-key' = "xxxxx"), query = list(oib = "18527887472"))
```

How to GET more objects in one line of code? Lets say I have a vector:

```
oibreq <- c("18527887472", "92680516748", "00045103869")
```

and I want to GET objects for this 3 "queries". Long way is to call  GET function 3 times:

```
 request1 <- GET(url = "https://api.data-api.io/xxxx", add_headers('x-dataapi-key' = "xxxx"), query = list(oib = "18527887472"))
request2 <- GET(url = "https://api.data-api.io/v1/eoglasna/", add_headers('x-dataapi-key' = "xxxx"), query = list(oib = "00045103869"))
request2 <- GET(url = "https://api.data-api.io/v1/eoglasna/", add_headers('x-dataapi-key' = "xxxx"), query = list(oib = "92680516748"))
```

Is there any faster way to do this? It's problem if I have 100 `oibreq`elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own function and then pass your vector of object ids to the function via `lapply()`:

```
my_get <- function(object) {
  GET(url = "https://api.data-api.io/v1/eoglasna/", 
      add_headers('x-dataapi-key' = "xxxx"), 
      query = list(oib = object))
}
lapply(oibreq, my_get)
```

Comment: I modify code to include additional functions: `my_get <- function(object) {
  fromJSON(toJSON(content(GET(url = "https://api.data-api.io/v1/eoglasna/", 
      add_headers('x-dataapi-key' = "59dd75a6525e"), 
      query = list(oib = object)), type = "application/json"), null = "null"), flatten = TRUE)
}
req1 <- lapply(oibreq, my_get) ` and it produce lists of lists of lists..., e. g. `[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]]$datum
[1] "2015-10-19T09:03:30+02:00"`

Comment: @Mislav Yes...that would make sense. But why are you using `fromJSON(toJSON(...))`...there's no need for `toJSON()` there.

Comment: Because it returns an error if I don't use `toJSON()`: `Error: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.` SO, I still don't get the desired result. I would like to get data.frame, but instead I get same strange object with list of lists...

Comment: @Mislav Take a look at `? content` which will automatically parse to json so you can skip all of that.

Answer (score 0):

I find an answer to my question:

```
req <- list()
my_get <- for (i in 1:length(oibreq)) {
  reqOP <- rbind(fromJSON(toJSON(content(GET(url = "https://api.data-api.io/v1/eoglasna/", 
                              add_headers('x-dataapi-key' = "xxx"), 
                              query = list(oib = oibreq[i])), type = "application/json"), null = "null"), flatten = TRUE))
  req[[i]] <- reqOP
}
big_data <- do.call(rbind, req)
```